# civicrm installed on dupal, theme has altered and contact summary layout editor has gone blank

Tags: theme

i cleared the cache under Administer/system settings/clean up caches and this has altered the theme and i cannot return it to previous theme. Contact Summary Editor is displaying blank and not working which was an existing problem resulting in me attempting the clean up cache.

Comment: Does system status work?

Comment: System status is saying: ok.

Comment: Have you checked your Drupal modules to make sure that CiviCRM Theme is enabled?